# How do I open a pdf with content URI on android >= 8?

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I am trying to open a pdf with existing installed pdf apps such as Google PDF Viewer. But the PDF screen shows blank.

I created an intent and used `ACTION_VIEW` filter but when I open in Google PDF it shows just blank screen nothing else even name of the file in Google PDF is not visible only document id (content-provider://..../document/122 <- this id) is shown

```java
String filePath = "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/346";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(filePath), "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
mActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "select an app to open this file"));
```

Comment: did you check if your `Uri` is valid? i mean if it points to valid pdf data?

Comment: Since you probably do not have read access to that document, you cannot grant read access to others. Where did you get that `Uri`, and why are you hard-coding it?

Comment: it is not hardcoded I put it for reference. I am storing the content URI which I get from the file picker in SQLite then later I use the same URI to show pdf. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

`setFlags` will replace all previous flags on intent. So use `addFlags` instead -

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

also check if you have long term access to content URI. After Android 4.3 you'll need to ask for persistent permission using `takePersistableUriPermission()` on content uri you get. Also you'll need to change `ACTION_VIEW` to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` where you are getting the URI you mentioned for `takePersistableUriPermission()` to work.
Read below articles for more clarification -
 - [About Using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider#search)
 - [How to use new Storage Access Framework to access/modify/create a file](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provide)